# Rewrite a sub DIR

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have created a website using IPB which I believe is written in PHP, the URL is the forum at present is 
what I would like is the URL to be rewritten to

and when user go to the index for force user to use instead of

any help with be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled and AllowOverride All is set in your conf file, and put these rules in the .htaccess file in the root of your web directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thereviewforum.com/$1 [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thereviewforum
RewriteRule ^forum(.*) http://community.thereviewforum.com$1 [R,L]
```

**EDIT** with full .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thereviewforum.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thereviewforum.com/$1 [R] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.thereviewforum 
RewriteRule ^forum/?(.*) http://community.thereviewforum.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```